# Filtering Nan with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have an array with shape (115, 2) and each column has 115 numbers. Some numbers are NaN in the 2nd column. How do I filter both columns with numpy to remove the NaN from the second column and the corresponding numbers in the first column?

Example

```py
array([[10., 10.],
       [20., 13.],
       [ 5., nan],
       [ 6., nan]])
```

to

```py
array([[10., 10.],
       [20., 13.]])
```

I want to filter both columns to exclude the values where the second column is NaN. I want to retain the shape so I can run statistics on the numbers like correlation. Any ideas?

If I try ~np.isnan the array loses its shape, which I want to retain. No pandas please!

Comment: what should the shape be when done?

Comment: it would be the number of rows with the remaining numbers (115-x) and two columns

Answer (score 1):

say, *data* is your numpy array. Then new-data would be your NaN removed numpy array

```
new_data = data[np.logical_not(np.isnan(data))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
arr[~np.isnan(arr[:,1])]
```

then

Filter the rows but only from a 1d array of booleans

I guess that when you say "I've tried `~np.isnan`", you mean that you have tried `arr[~np.isnan(arr)]`. But then, since `arr` is 2D (shape (115,2)), so is `~na.isnan(arr)`, which is a (115,2) shaped boolean array. In which case, what indexing from such array gives is all values of `arr` matching `True`. And without the original shape (how could it keep the original shape, since you may have not the same number of elements in both column).

`~na.isnan(arr[:,1])` on the other hand is a 1D (115,) array of booleans. Indexing with this just select the rows.

See example of indexing with arrays of booleans

```py
arr=np.arange(10).reshape(5,-1)
#array([[0, 1],
#       [2, 3],
#       [4, 5],
#       [6, 7],
#       [8, 9]])

# Indexing with a 2D-array of booleans (same shape as arr, so 5x2 here

arr[[[True, False], [False, False], [True, True], [False, False], [False, True]]]
#array([0, 4, 5, 9])
# I select the 1st element of 1st row, both elements of 3rd row, and last element of last row, so 0,4,5,9

# Indexing only along 1st axis, so with a 1d-array of 5 booleans, to select rows
arr[[True, False, True, True, False]]
#array([[0, 1],
#       [4, 5],
#       [6, 7]])
# I selected 1st, 3rd and 4th rows
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure what you mean by filter the rows but only from 1d array of booleans. Can you please explain?